# How can i get decimal place upto 4

Tags: formula, decimal

Below is my code which is giving me decimal places upto 2. But I want to get decimal upto 4. Please help

```
IF( 
          Final_Amount_with_exch_rate__c>= 1000000, 
          TEXT(FLOOR(Final_Amount_with_exch_rate__c/ 1000000)) & ",", 
          "") & 
        IF( 
          Final_Amount_with_exch_rate__c>= 1000, 
          RIGHT(TEXT(FLOOR(Final_Amount_with_exch_rate__c/ 1000)), 3) & ",", 
          "") & 
        RIGHT(TEXT(FLOOR(Final_Amount_with_exch_rate__c)), 3) & "." & 
        IF( 
          MOD(Final_Amount_with_exch_rate__c, 1) * 100 < 10, 
          "0" & TEXT(ROUND(MOD(Final_Amount_with_exch_rate__c, 1), 2) * 100), 
                TEXT(MIN(ROUND(MOD(Final_Amount_with_exch_rate__c, 1), 2) * 100, 99)) 
        )
```

Answer (score 3):

```
ROUND   Returns the nearest number to a number you specify, constraining the new number by a specified number of digits.
```

In your round method you are giving 2 Just change into 4. It will solve your problem.

To display in VF page use this approach.

```
<apex:outputText value="{0, number, 00.0000}">
      <apex:param value="{!Account.AnnualRevenue}" />  //Your field here
</apex:outputText>
```

Comment: I already tried changing 2 to 4. but no changes happening...

Comment: @SfdcPro are you display this value in VF page or using in controller?

Comment: I am displaying field on detail page.

Comment: @SfdcPro Please check my updated answer.